# Why does "at work" make as much sense as "working" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

I'm struggling to explain to someone why the following two sentences are both correct:

1. "Students, though not necessarily **working** in the society, are also important members"
2. "Students, though not necessarily **at work** in the society, are also important members"

As I understand it, "working" is a present participle, but what is "at work" best described as? Is it simply a preposition squished together with a verb, or is there a more specific grammatical name for the elements at play???

Thanks!

Comment: [Used without a helping verb, the present participle functions as an adjective.](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/present-participle-as-adjective/) In your example, if it weren't for the syntactically irrelevant ***in the society***, I might expect ***in work*** rather than ***at work***. If a college made special arrangements [for in-work students](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22for+in+work+students%22) they'd often be hyphenated in that sequence, but not when referring to them as *students in work* (i.e. *employed, with a job*).

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-work) have good examples showing the different meanings the fixed phrase 'at work' is used with. It's a prepositional phrase, but the example 'He's not in at the moment – he's at work' uses a more spatially tied prepositional sense than 'They are at work trying to overthrow the dictator' does. Though 'work' here certainly invokes action / taking a stance, it would not be analysed as a verb.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done.

Comment: Even though not a native speaker I am, the difference is clear. 1 conveys "Students who **are not required to work** in society are also important members. Whereas, 2 conveys somewhat vague. If I hear the sentence, I would probably ask "what work? Do you have a job? Or do you mean your work ( homework )?"

Comment: Can not upvote any of answers sorry.

Comment: owowowowo wait, Could someone update please. The "discussion" is not over. Anything is not clarified in any field.

Answer (score 1):

"Working" generally implies active participation, You are doing something right now.

"At Work" means that the person in question is currently at a place where work is being conducted, though they could or couldn't be actually working at the time.

When preceded by "not necessarily", the statements following become ambiguous. Because of this, with both statements the implication that the students aren't actively participating (but are valued nonetheless) is being conveyed.

Comment: ' "At Work" means that the person in question is currently at a place where work is being conducted': so 'Those former students who are at work in the society are obviously important members' would mean they never leave their place of work? No, this is a different sense of 'at work': _employed_.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "at work" indicates a state in which the student is working at a job, not a generic activity. When someone is having dinner with the folks they are "at table". This is different than just being in proximity to furniture.

As a part of speech I don't have a better answer than yours but the difference is real.

Comment: I would say that "at work" does not necessarily mean being employed. Volunteers and activists can both be described as being "at work in society" the former performing useful functions and the latter trying to change things. People running foodbanks are "at work" providing food and climate change activists are "at work" trying to change the way the world works. In most cases these people are either "in work" as well because they need to live or they are pensioned or drawing benefits to sustain themselves. Those "in work" often see the paid job as less significant than the voluntary one.

Answer (score -1):

I think the sentences mean different things. The first is ambiguous, it could be taken to mean that having students in the society is not working, whilst the second is clearly considering the work students do, or don't, put into it.

Answer (score -1):

Your real problem, Elaine, is that neither sentence properly expresses the idea you are trying to express.

It is very odd to say that a student is not working.  That is what students are supposed to be doing!  It is also a little odd to say that a student is “not at work”.  If she is in a lecture, then she cannot be ‘at work’ at that time.  That would means she has a job and is ‘at work’ at the time.  So I guess you mean ‘is IN work’ (= ‘has a paid job’).  The fact that a student is not in work does not mean she is not a useful member of society.

Forgive me, but I think English is not your first language.  The tell tale word is ‘the’ before ‘society’.  In most European languages other than English and Greek, abstract nouns have the definite article in front them:  ‘la vie’, ‘la vita’ ...  So you cannot say “in the society”.  You should say “in society”.

The better way of saying it is:-
“Students, though not necessarily in work, are still useful members of society.”

“

Comment: Is this a BrE thing?  i am not aware of anyone in AmE who would use the term ***in work*** to mean “has a paid job”.  We would say ***employed***. “in work” sounds like “not fully developed- still in the process of being created”

Comment: @Jim It must be as you say.  The press, statisticians and Government departments, as well as politicians, constantly speak of people ‘in work’ and ‘out of work’.  It is not necessarily exactly the same as ‘unemployed’.  But they are similar.

Comment: Interesting now that you point it out- we do say “out of work” ...

Comment: Wait, wait wait please. **The better way of saying it is:- “Students, though not necessarily in work, are still useful members of society** sounds like though the students do not study, they are important in the society. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @KentaroTomono  “To be IN work” is to be engaged in some form of paid employment, including self-employment.  The fact that a student is not ‘in work’ does not imply that he or she is not working:   a student works by studying; carers work by caring for their children or an ageing child.  Neither is described as IN work.

Comment: This is the first time I heard the word "in work" as Jim says.... **at work**  in my opinion would suggest you are uhm...at work, lol, meaning, you are engaging in your current job. Isn't it a not nice tactic to change the OP's question?  I personally think...though I can not give much information since I am not a native speaker...

Comment: @Tuffy The student and the carer, however, are "at work" when they are studying or caring. This, however, is different from being "at work in society". See my comment on Elliot's  answer above.

Answer (score -1):

Both these constructions are grammatically correct and may be used interchangeably in this example, because they may both be translated as "students do not have jobs in society".